# Standalone identity server 4 Username lookup

Tags: c#, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

What is the recommended way to obtain user details from standalone identity server 4?

I have an api and auth server as separate entities. Lot of resources in api have auth user ids attached to it and on UI I would like to display real user names. While there is an obvious solution, add api methods to identity server that would return these based on provided ids, I was wondering if there is any best practice concerning this.

I have some weird feeling about exposing user info in api even if it's lookup based on id. Theoretically anybody can obtain these ids. I am only interested in given_name, family_name and username claims so maybe these are public enough and I am overthinking.

Other option would be to setup server to server communication which increases the load though so I am not very excited about that tbh. How are you dealing with this?

Comment: Well, how are you building the identity upon login? How does the IdSrv validate the login request?

Comment: This is not about authorization, it's more about lookup of user data based on user id. I think where you're leading with this comment is the user token. I don't have that as it's a lookup for multiple users at the time. E.g. data table

Comment: No, what I asked is how does the IdSrv communicate with the authentication system. For example, I have an IdSrv with ASP.NET Core Identity so it acts both as authorization and authentication server, and we have endpoints there to manage users

Comment: Same here, pretty simple setup. If my api and my auth/authorization server was the same entity, it would be as easy as injecting the usermanager and obtaining the data from the db, however that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an Authentication Server(IdSrvr4), and an Authorization Server.

If you have said user's token, use the built-in [Identity Server UserInfo Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html).

For anything custom, we implement in Authorization Server.  So If you want given_name and family_name of other users, we have a custom endpoint for that.  And that custom endpoint uses custom Authorization Filters and uses a direct call to the database(We use EF & MS Identity).

Update due to Comments.
We chose 2 Servers, 1 for Authentication and 1 for Authorization.  This design was in part informed by this article titled ["Identity vs Permissions"](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/) and written by an author of IdentityServer4.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, thanks man good to know. The need is to get details of many users (usually in table, counting 25 rows min) so the userinfo wouldn't work as I'd have to call it many times. Custom api would be better.

Comment: "We have an Authentication Server(IdSrVr4), and an Authorization Server.", you got it backwards. IdSrv is an authorization server, not an authentication one

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto - I don't believe you are correct.  IdSrvr authenticates that you are in fact who you say you are(Authentication).  It does not address what you are allowed to do(Authorization).

Comment: Quite the opposite, IdSrv explicitly leaves authentication outside of the system so that you can use, for example, ASP.NET Core Identity or Active Directory for authenticating. Even more, IdSrv is exactly for addressing what a user (normally in a specific client) is allowed to do

Comment: Ok well either way, it doesn't change much for me tbh. I use IdentityServer4 with net core identity. The task is simply to obtain user details if I have user id from the front end. It definitely seems custom api method for this is the way to go. Cheers guys ;)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Here is documentation [Identity vs Permissions](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/) written by one of the authors of IdSrvr.  Explains that IdSrvr is for Authentication and why its not suited for Authorization.

Comment: This is how they propose to solve the 'Authorization problem'. Take a look at the [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/).

Comment: Oh cool, I knew they were working on it, but not that it was done..  I wanted, but never got around to implementing what amounted to an ETAG for Authorization and then including just the ETAG as a claim in the Authentication Token.  I'll have to read up on PolicyServer.